# ElasticSearch Performance : Continuous read/write vs Bulk write

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic Search. I need to implement a system where I will be getting data feed continuously throughout the day. I would like to make this data feed searchable so I am using ElasticSearch.

Now, I have two ways to go about this:
1) Store data from the feed in mongo. And feed this data to ElasticSearch at regular interval, let say twice a day.
2) Directly feed data to ElasticSearch which is s continuous process. At the same time ElasticSearch has to perform search queries.

I am expecting a volume of around 20 entries per second coming from data feed and around 2-3 queries per second being performed by ElasticSearch.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you tell us more about your cluster architecture? How many nodes? All nodes have data or also gateway nodes?
Usually I would say feeding directly to elasticsearch shouldn't be a problem. 2-3 queries per second is not much at all for elasticsearch.

Comment: I will be using single node to begin with. Do you think ES can handle it's own indexing while at the same time serving queries without hampering performance ?

Comment: Of course it won't be as fast as without writing at the same time but the question is if it too slow. I would say it will be still fast enough. You could setup your cluster and test the performance before u decide for one option...

Comment: What would happen or be a preffered option if the writes could be 500-600  per second. Same with the reads.

Answer (score 1):

You should optimize your index structure and application code for it:

1. Create separate index for each day
2. Increase number of shards (you
   should experiment, based on your hardware configuration)
3. For old
   days indexes you should close them or aggregate into big periods
   (another month indexes) using some batch processing

from my tests 20 inserts/second is not a big load for elasticsearch